# more about vimrc configuration

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am new to Vim and after using it for about 3 days i am in love with it. I used sublime-text before this and i decided to try vim because i heard a lot of people (*maybe some*) hate and love it. I know that learning Vim require time investment + patience but for the basic shortcut and command I am okay *preety smooth* but when i reach the .vimrc configuration I start to feel frustrated and 'uhhh'. Overall I like the way how the work-flow goes and in the past 3 days i manage to implement the basic shortcut.

I watched and read a lot of tutorial, and most of it asked *us* to find "someones .vimrc configuration and use it". I searched at Google 'vim .vimrc', I found 2 links from Github and I am amazed with all the massive lines and I was like 'What! How am i going to understand what each of this line for!' :/ i tried to search all the 'set' and the basic config but i am not happy without knowing what each of the line does. Please if anyone here can help me or explain how the configuration works. I tried the :help and there were about 8000 lines .>< for now i am using the https://github.com/tpope/vim-sensible Vim-Sensible and i am hoping to know how it work. Thanks guys.

For plugin, I think it's fine for now.

Comment: I suggest keeping my [idiomatic vimc gist](https://gist.github.com/romainl/9ecd7b09a693816997ba) handy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you see in people's posted `~/.vimrc` files either is:

- the result of years of using and tweaking Vim; don't be intimitated, just start out small and it will grow automatically with your continues use (hopefully in a benign way). The mentioned *vim-sensible* plugin is a good way to start.
- just copied from colleagues / somewhere on the net without real understanding; this is dangerous and best avoided. Vim "distributions" like *spf-13* and *Janus* lure you with a quick install and out-of-the-box settings, but you pay the price with increased complexity (you need to understand both Vim's runtime loading scheme and the arbitrary conventions of the distribution) and inflexibility (the distribution may make some things easier, but other things very difficult). Vim is incredibly customizable, using someone else's customization makes no sense. Doubly so for canned, ready-made "distributions".

Yes, the built-in `:help` is large, but you don't need to read it in one go :-) It is excellent, too, and contains most of what you need - for years to come!

[This article by Vim's creator](http://www.moolenaar.net/habits.html) explains the philosophy behind Vim very well (there's also a recorded talk): start small, using only basic commands (also taught by `vimtutor`), and gradually become a master of all kinds of text editing tasks!

Comment: The 7 habits should be required reading before even doing `$ vimtutor`.